# How to orbit several objects at different speeds and paths around a central location

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints, parent, empty

I am attempting to make spheres orbit around the perimeter of elliptic rings that transect a rotating central sphere, similar to an electron orbiting around a nucleus. The rings and attached spheres also follow the rotation of the central sphere around its axis (see reference image). The rings do not have an independent path. I have successfully rotated the entire object using an empty as a parent, but I need the smaller spheres to orbit along the elliptic path of their rings while also following the rotation of the sphere. When I set the rings to be the parent of the small spheres, they move position. Any advice on how to do this?

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Just kidding! I solved it by using axes and follow path

Comment: if you solved your own problem: you are encouraged to answer your own question, provid[ng a working solution for your problem!